# refresh chat section in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i working on chat system and i need to refresh chat section to display new messages was sent with ajax , this is my message blade

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">messenger</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @if($array)
                            @foreach ($array as $message)
                                @foreach ($message->messages_reply as $reply)
                                    <li>  {{ $reply['msg']}} </li>
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                        <br >
                        <form method="post" action="{{url("sendMessage")}}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_from" value="{{$from}}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="user_to" value="{{$to}}">
                            <input type="hidden" name="date" value="{{time()}}">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="msg">
                            <br >
                            <input type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add a class to the <li class="class_name"></li>. And after successfully insertion of message add that message below the last li tag by ajax (append)

Comment: then reload the page by "window.location.reload" in success state of the ajax

Comment: You wrote, you want to display new messages which was sent by ajax. So you use ajax. Show us how you add a new message into your table.

Comment: class messages extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['user_from','user_to','date'];

    public function messages_reply()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(messages_replay::class , 'messages_id');
    }
    public function user_from()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'user_from');
    }
    public function user_to()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'user_to');
    }
}

Comment: this is my model

Comment: edit your question and that model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ajax for submiting a new message.

Add 1 ID to the submit button

```
<input type="submit" id="sendMessage" value="send" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

And add this ajax in your blade file

```
$("body").on("click","#sendMessage",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var user_from= $("#user_from").val();
                var user_to= $("#user_to").val();
                var date= $("#date").val();
                var msg= $("#msg").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"{{url('sendMessage')}}",
                    data: {"user_from": user_from,"user_to": user_to,"date":date,"msg":msg},
                    success:function(res){
                       // Reload the page as you wanated
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Add this to your blade file

Comment: res is the result which you got it back from the ajax call. Or you can say the return value of the ajax.

Comment: If you are not aware of ajax completely better to go through the documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Glad I could help!